# Hibernate search too many results

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-search

I want to return records from database using hibernate search. I have difficulties when the search string is actually a phrase, otherwise things looks OK.
I have several fields on which I make the search and I do not know runtime on which field I should make the query so I made a BooleanJunction and used the `should` DSL method like this:

```
final Query spatialLuceneQuery = queryBuilder.spatial().within(200, Unit.KM).ofLatitude(latitude)
            .andLongitude(longitude).createQuery();
bool.must(spatialLuceneQuery);

if (tag != null) {
    if (isPhrase(tag.getTag())) {
        final Query phraseTagsLuceneQuery = queryBuilder.phrase().withSlop(2).onField("tags").sentence(tag.getTag()).createQuery();
        final Query phraseNameLuceneQuery = queryBuilder.phrase().onField("name").sentence(tag.getTag()).createQuery();
        final Query phraseDescriptionLuceneQuery = queryBuilder.phrase().withSlop(3).onField("description").sentence(tag.getTag()).createQuery();
        final Query phraseActiveSkillsLuceneQuery = queryBuilder.phrase().withSlop(1).onField("activeSkills").sentence(tag.getTag()).createQuery();
        bool.should(phraseTagsLuceneQuery).should(phraseActiveSkillsLuceneQuery).should(phraseNameLuceneQuery).should(phraseDescriptionLuceneQuery);
    } else {
        final Query fuzzyLuceneQuery = queryBuilder.keyword().fuzzy().withEditDistanceUpTo(2).withPrefixLength(1).onFields("tags", "activeSkills","name","description").matching(tag.getTag()).createQuery();
        bool.must(fuzzyLuceneQuery);
    }
}
```

When the `isPhrase` method returns true all the records in the table are returned. How can I restrict the results to the relevant ones?

Mapping looks like this:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "USER_INDEXED_SEARCH")
@Indexed
@Spatial(spatialMode = SpatialMode.RANGE)
@AnalyzerDef(name = "customAnalyzer", tokenizer = @TokenizerDef(factory = StandardTokenizerFactory.class) , filters = {
    @TokenFilterDef(factory = LowerCaseFilterFactory.class),
    @TokenFilterDef(factory = ASCIIFoldingFilterFactory.class),
    @TokenFilterDef(factory = SnowballPorterFilterFactory.class, params = {
            @Parameter(name = "language", value = "Romanian") }) })
public class UserIndexedSearch extends DefaultLoggable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = -8021827814963060426L;

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@DocumentId
@Column(name = "USER_INDEXED_SEARCH_ID")
private Integer userIndexSearchId;

@Latitude
@Column(name = "LATITUDE")
private Double lat;

@Longitude
@Column(name = "LONGITUDE")
private Double lon;

@Column(name = "USER_ID")
private Integer userId;

@Field(index = Index.YES, analyze = Analyze.YES, store = Store.NO)
@Analyzer(definition = "customAnalyzer")
@Column(name = "TAGS")
private String tags;

@Field(index = Index.YES, analyze = Analyze.YES, store = Store.NO)
@Analyzer(definition = "customAnalyzer")
@Column(name = "ACTIVE_AREAS")
private String activeAreas;

@Field(index = Index.YES, analyze = Analyze.YES, store = Store.NO)
@Analyzer(definition = "customAnalyzer")
@Column(name = "ACTIVE_SKILLS")
private String activeSkills;

@Field(index = Index.YES, analyze = Analyze.YES, store = Store.NO)
@Analyzer(definition = "customAnalyzer")
@Column(name = "NAME")
private String name;

@Field(index = Index.YES, analyze = Analyze.YES, store = Store.NO)
@Analyzer(definition = "customAnalyzer")
@Column(name = "DESCRIPTION")
private String description;
```

Thank you!

Comment: How does your actual data look like? Can you make an example? You are using a phrase query where your phrase is a tag? That sounds a bit odd. What does the tags field contain? If it is a single tag I don't understand why you would use a phrase query here. Can you explain why you use this query type?

Comment: I have the same questions as Hardy. Would like to add that often what you're after is not to exclude many results, but to get the "top N" most relevant results. If you avoid an explicit sort, the most relevant will be on top. See also "Projections" in the docs to have it show the scores and explanation for each result, that's useful to understand the scoring system.

Comment: Yes, I am using a sorter based on distance and I want filter out results that are under a score

Answer (score 1):

When You will find yourself sometimes puzzled by a result showing up in a query or a result not showing
up in a query.Hibernate Search 
gives you access to the Lucene Explanation object for a given result (in a given query). This
class is considered fairly advanced to Lucene users but can provide a good understanding of the
scoring of an object. You have two ways to access the Explanation object for a given result:

- Use the fullTextQuery.explain(int) method
- Use projection

Example using projection:

```
FullTextQuery ftQuery = s.createFullTextQuery( luceneQuery, Dvd.class )
        .setProjection( FullTextQuery.DOCUMENT_ID, FullTextQuery.EXPLANATION, FullTextQuery.THIS );
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked") List<Object[]> results = ftQuery.list();
for (Object[] result : results) {
    Explanation e = (Explanation) result[1];
    display( e.toString() );
}
```